# Using multi_terms with nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search and I am trying to create an aggregation that counts pairs of fields in buckets. I started with the following as a naive solution:

```
"aggs": {
        "type_for_type": {
          "multi_terms": {
            "terms": [
              {
                "field": "@type"
              },
              {
                "field": "@type"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

and it works but it is a naive implementation as it matches the same field. However the second field is a nested one so I tried the following:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "aggregated": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "field.test"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "types_for_regions": {
          "multi_terms": {
            "terms": [
              {
                "field": "@type"
              },
              {
                "field": "field.test.label.keyword"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but the buckets returned are empty, because the second field needs to be nested. Any idea how I can combine *multi_terms* with *nested*?